# What is the word for the action of speaking good in front of someone but complaining about them behind their back?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person always complaining like "he is said about you, like that" to another person.

Complaining about you to others and speaking good in front of you like a double game.

Scenario:  Guy  "a" says to b, "c is talking bad about you" and going to c and telling b is talking bad about you.

2 Going to manager and complaining what that guy said about you at lunch.

What is the right word?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to convey with "he is said about you, like that". Can you try rephrasing or elaborating? Also add 3-4 examples, please.

Comment: You already said that. Can you elaborate on the specific kind of complaint you were asking about with "he is said about you, like that"? Also, please [edit] this additional information into your question itself. Don't put it in further comments.

Comment: Do you mean a gossip?  "He said things like that about you"?  Was he was talking about you and criticizing?

Comment: He may be a hypocrite, or wise to avoid insulting you to your face.   There is no "right word or insulting word" guaranteed.

Comment: @DanBron added a scenario

Comment: I think OP is asking about when someone *bad mouth*s you behind your back and smiles and is friendly to your face.  A *two-faced, low-down, bad-mouthin’ son-of-...*

Comment: @Jim  yes Jim like that .. is there any noun for that

Comment: Yea it's gossip, a backstabber, being two-faced, "talking out of both sides of your mouth" (don't use this - it's a more advanced but common metaphor in the US to mean someone is using double talk or talking one way with this set of people and another way with this set). The best one is probably what @YosefBaskin suggested, "gossiper".

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're talking about is a slang term, *[two-faced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/two-faced)*.

From Merriam-Webster:

> ## Two-Faced
>
> ### *adjective*
>
> #### Definition of two–faced for English Language Learners
>
> Not honest or sincere: saying different things to different people in order to get their approval instead of speaking and behaving honestly

Hopefully this is what you were looking for. (:

Comment: Two-faced backbiting

Answer (score 1):

The activity may also be called [***backstabbing***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backstabbing), and the person doing it a ***backstabber***:

> betrayal (as by a verbal attack against one not present) especially by a false friend
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backstabbing)*</sub>

A typical work example would be if two people (A and B) are assigned to a project together.  A repeatedly tells B how great it is to be working together and how well B is doing; but A also repeatedly tells the boss that B is not doing their part of the job, and that A should be made the project leader and be allowed to replace B with someone else.  Person A is *backstabbing* person B in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Talebearer** (*noun*)

*Merriam Webster*:

> one that spreads gossip or rumors;

*Webster's Dictionary 1828 - Online Edition*:

> A person who officiously tells tales; one who impertinently communicates intelligence or anecdotes, and makes mischief in society by his officiousness.